# Autofill cells from second sheet based on input in first sheet - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 'main' sheet where i input data everyday. I want to make it auto, as much as possible. My idea is to create one sheet which will be my database where i will have columns ID, Name, Number, Address etc. And when i put a values in ID column on my 'main' sheet, other columns in that sheet(Name,Number,Address) should auto fill from 'database' sheet.
Is that possible?

Comment: Yes. Is you want a longer answer, please, share some code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you need something like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:C, Sheet2!D2:F, {2,3}, 1), ))
```

where A and D are IDs and E:F is your database and B:C will return your data from the database

[image]